# Which one is a Jyotirlinga "Omkareshwar" or "Mamleshwar"

Tags: jyotirlinga

I have read in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omkareshwar#Legends%20and%20history) about **Omkareshwar Jyotirlinga**. Before I knew this one is called **Omkareshwar**, But when I read in wiki, they call it **Mamleshwar**. I got confused. Can anyone give insight on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omkareswara is the 4th one among the total 12 Jyotirlingams.

It is situated in Shivapuri or Mamaleswara, a place in Madhya Pradesh.

Refer to the "Dwadasa Jyotirlinga Stotram" found [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dwadasa_Jyothir_Linga_Stotram):

> Sourashtre Somanadham, cha Sri Shaile Mallikarjunam, Ujjayinyam Maha
>   Kalam, **Omkara Mamaleshwaram**, Paralyam Vaidyanatham, cha Dakinyam
>   Bhimasankaram,

Meaning of the words in bold:
**In Mamaleswara the Jyotirlinga is called Omkara.**

So,both "Omkareswara" and "Mamaleswara" refer to the same Jyotirlingam with Mamaleswara referring to the place where the Jyotirlinaga is situated and Omkareswara to the name or the form of the Lingam.

Also refer to [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/12jyotirlingas.htm) page ,where the name of the 12 Jyotirlingams are given in bold:

> The Dwadasa Jyotirlinga Stotra Saurashtre **Somanaatham** Cha Sree Shaile
>   **Mallikarjunam** Ujjayinyaam **Mahaakaalam** **Omkaare** Mamaleswaram Himalaye to
>   **Kedaram** Daakinyaam **Bhimashankaram** Vaaranaasyaam cha **Viswesam**
>   **Trayambakam** Gowtameethate Paralyaam **Vaidyanaatham** cha **Naagesam**
>   Daarukaavane Setubandhe **Ramesham** **Grushnesam** cha Shivaalaye

**Edit-**
 I'm adding yet another source which says exactly the opposite of what is being said in the above.It says Omkara is the place where the Jyotirlingam is situated and the Lingam is called Amareswara.

It is a stotram composed by Nandi(the Bull) and is found in the Shiva Purana.

Quoting from [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/shivapuranam22.html) page,the following is the description of the 12 Jyotirlingams as given by Nandi:

> Kedaro Himavatprushthe Daakinyaam Bhimasankarah
>
> Vaaranaasyam cha Viswestriumbako Gautami thatey
>
> Saurashtrey Sommanathasva Srisaile Mallikarjunah
>
> Ujjainyam Maha Kala **Omkare cha Amaresvarah**
>
> Vaidyanathaaschitha bhumo Nagesho Daarukaananey
>
> Sethu bandhe cha Ramesho Ghrusneswara Siva lingo
>
> Avatara Dvadasakamethchhambhoh Paramatmana
>
> Nandiswara described the Most Celebrated Twelve Jyotirlingas of Maha
>   Deva as follows:
>
> Kedarnath in Himalayas
>
> Bhima Sankar in Dakinya
>
> Viswesvara in Varanasi
>
> Triambaka on the banks of River Gautami
>
> Somnatha in Saurashtra
>
> Mallikarjuna in Sri Sailam
>
> Maha Kala in Ujjain
>
> **Amareswara at Omkara**
>
> Vaidyanatha in Chitha Bhumi
>
> Nagesa at Daruka
>
> Rameswara at Setu Bandhana, and
>
> Ghrishneswara

Also if you see the images of the 12 Jyotirlingams in the above page then you will find  that the fourth Jyotirlingam there is mentioned collectively as

> Sri Omakaramamaleswara,Sri Amalaeswara

Now, both of them can't be a Jyotirlingam each because there are only 12 of them & not 13.

So,both taken together constitutes one Jyotirlingam.This is the most rational and acceptable answer.

Comment: But in wiki, It is written: *On a request of all the gods and the sages Lord Shiva made two parts of the lingas. One half is called Omkareshwara and the other Mamaleshwar or Amareshwar.*

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I have added another link.Omkareswar is the Jyotirlingam and Mamaleswar refers to the place.

Comment: In wiki, it is also written, *There is a bridge over Narmada river connecting Omkareshwar temple and Mamleshwar temple.*

Comment: Omkareswara is the Jyotirlinga.Another temple is certainly there ,its called Amaraswara or Mamleswara like u have said, but that is not the Jyotirlingam as per the Dwadasa Jyotirlinga Stotram.So,the answer to ur question is-OMKARESWARA.

Comment: The first link you shared in your answer, there also, it is written, *"Other story says that the Shivalinga was split into two upon the request of the Devas. Thus, the formation of Omkareshwara and Amareshwar."*

Comment: Hence both of 'em counted as one among 12 Jyotirlinga

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Check now.I have modified my answer with more citations.:).Hopefully now you'll be satisfied.

Comment: lol that *last edit* . You have dug a lot. I give you that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> सौराष्ट्रे सोमनाथंच श्री शैले मल्लिकार्जुनम् |
> उज्जयिन्यां महाकालमोंकारममलेश्वरम् ||

In this verse, Mamleshwar in Omkareshwar region is called Jyotirlinga. Both Omkareshwar and Mamaleshwar are in the form of the same Jyotirlinga, Mamaleshwar on the south bank of the Narmada and Omkareshwar sits on the Omkar Parvat towards the north and the mother Narmada sits in the middle.

Reference: [Mamleshwar Jyotirlinga](https://www.jagghoomiya.com/mamleshwar/)